# If user skips rows to input a numeric value, force user to type in data in the following available row

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

I have a sheet and the user input Starts in A7 and calculations are inserted with a macro to B7 all the way through I.

I got all that worked out but what i need is: the user is going down typing in data in Column A, lets say they input data Starting from A7, through A11, then skip A12 and type into A13, i want the sheet to automatically move the user's input into A12 so there's never any blank rows IN BETWEEN the data in column A.

Ideally all the data should be in sequence and there shouldn't be any blank rows in between the data entered in column A.

Here is the code i have come up with thus far:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

1    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:C")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Row >= Range("FormulaRange").Row + 1 Then
            If Target.Row <= Range("RowTracker").Value + 1 Then
            Dim t
            RWS = Target.rows.Count
            COLS = Target.Columns.Count
                For r = 1 To RWS
                    For c = 1 To COLS
                        If Not IsNumeric(Target.rows.Cells(r, c).Value) Then
                        'Else
                            MsgBox "Please enter only numeric values."
                            Application.Undo
                            'End
                            Else

                        If Target.rows.Cells(r, 2) = "" Then Target.rows.Cells(r, 2) = 0
                        If Target.rows.Cells(r, 3) = "" Then Target.rows.Cells(r, 3) = 0

                        End If
                   Next c
                Next r
            Else

            MsgBox "Please enter data in the next available line."

            Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Right now it detects if i skip rows and input arbitrarily in A giving me a warning not to do so but i would love it just took my input and put it back into the next available row in column A.

I thought about doing a Row.Delete but the way the code is set up is keeps detecting the deleted row as skipping cells in A column continuously giving me the error of "Please Enter Data in the next available line."

Comment: Were you deleting row from top down or bottom up?

Comment: @urdearboy i was using something similar to this For i = xRows To 1 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WorkRng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
        WorkRng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp
    End If
Next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key point missing is to prevent a cascade of events as you change the sheet.  Use `Application.EnableEvent = False` to prevent this.

Then deleting rows with blanks will work, something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    On Error GoTo EH
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("A:C")) Is Nothing Then
        rw = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Prevent a cascade of events
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For i = rw To 1 Step -1
            'Check for blanks in column A, delete row if found
            If IsEmpty(Me.Cells(i, 1)) Then
                Me.Rows(i).Delete
            End If

            'check for non numeric data
            For j = 1 To 3
                If Not IsNumeric(Me.Cells(i, j)) Then
                    Me.Cells(i, j).ClearContents
                End If
                'Enter Zeros's
                If j > 1 Then
                    If IsEmpty(Me.Cells(i, j)) Then
                        Me.Cells(i, j) = 0
                    End If
                End If
            Next

        Next
    End If
EH:
    ' restore event handling
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. The delete rows and check for non numeric/blanks will interact, possibly in ways you don't expect
2. If user leaves column A blank and enters data into other columns, it will be deleted
3. I've left out the Named Range checks, as I'm unsure what they are doing.  You can reinstate to suit.

Might be better to validate and warn the user before deleting

Comment: I think this might do the trick.  Also just to let you know, the actual data that gets input by the user starts in A7 and down... so would i have to change the the Target, Me.Columns("A:C") to Target, Me.Columns("A7:C") ? 

Because when i tried this, there's a few titles and instructions above A7 with empty rows and all that got deleted when i tried.

Comment: Just change to `For i = rw to 7 step -1`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will force the user to only stay in the next possible row for column A without being able to enter more information.

This isn't foolproof, but will get you started. You can extend as needed:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row <> 1 Then
        If Len(Target.Offset(-1)) = 0 Then
            Target.Offset(-1).Select
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't handle if `Target` is more than one cell.  Especially a problem if user copies a block of data including blank(s) into column A

Comment: @chrisneilsen - agreed. hence my *This isn't foolproof, but will get you started. You can extend as needed:* comment. I didn't want to come up with all possible scenarios for code I know little about.